# Adding product with variations in Amazon XML

Tags: xml, laravel, amazon-selling-partner-api

When I open this product in amazon I have message **"This SKU has an inconsistent product classification with the ASIN. Please submit a feed to update this SKU to match the ASIN product classification."**

What is wrong here, and does anyone can help me, because I can't find solution few days? I tried like in example under this text.

```
  $fileContent = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
        <AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
                <Header>
                  <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
                  <MerchantIdentifier>' . $merchantIdentifier . '</MerchantIdentifier>
                </Header>
                <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
                <PurgeAndReplace>false</PurgeAndReplace>
                <Message>
                  <MessageID>1</MessageID>
                  <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
                  <Product>
                    <SKU>'.$amazonProduct->master_sku.'</SKU>
                    <StandardProductID>
                    <Type>ASIN</Type>
                    <Value>STTU755C01</Value>
                </StandardProductID>
                    <ProductTaxCode>A_GEN_NOTAX</ProductTaxCode>
                    <DescriptionData>
                      <Title>'.$amazonProduct->title.'</Title>
                      <Brand>'.$amazonProduct->distributionChannelTeam->brand->name.'</Brand>
                      <Description>'.preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', ' ', $amazonProduct->description).'</Description>
                      <MSRP currency="EUR">25.19</MSRP>
                      <Manufacturer>Example Product Manufacturer</Manufacturer>
                      <ItemType>'.preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', ' ', $amazonProduct->product->baseProduct->category->name).'</ItemType>
                      <CountryOfOrigin>DE</CountryOfOrigin>
                      <UnitCount>1</UnitCount>
                      <PPUCountType>stück</PPUCountType>
                      <IsExpirationDatedProduct>false</IsExpirationDatedProduct>
                    </DescriptionData>
                    <ProductData>
                        <Home> 
                        <ProductType>
                            <BedAndBath>
                            <IdentityPackageType>traditional</IdentityPackageType>
                            </BedAndBath>
                            </ProductType>
                        <Parentage>parent</Parentage>
                         <VariationData> 
                         <VariationTheme>Size-Color</VariationTheme>
                          <Size>XS</Size>
                          <Color>blue</Color>
                          </VariationData> 
                          <Material>cotton</Material> 
                          <ThreadCount>10</ThreadCount> 
                        </Home>
                    </ProductData>
                    <IsHeatSensitive>false</IsHeatSensitive>
                  </Product>
                </Message>
    
                <Message>
                  <MessageID>2</MessageID>
                  <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
                  <Product>
                    <SKU>MAKAM</SKU>
                    <ProductTaxCode>A_GEN_NOTAX</ProductTaxCode>
                    <DescriptionData>
                      <Title>'.$amazonProduct->title.'</Title>
                      <Brand>'.$amazonProduct->distributionChannelTeam->brand->name.'</Brand>
                      <Description>'.preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', ' ', $amazonProduct->description).'</Description>
                      <MSRP currency="EUR">25.19</MSRP>
                      <Manufacturer>Example Product Manufacturer</Manufacturer>
                      <ItemType>'.preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', ' ', $amazonProduct->product->baseProduct->category->name).'</ItemType>
                      <CountryOfOrigin>DE</CountryOfOrigin>
                      <UnitCount>1</UnitCount>
                      <PPUCountType>stück</PPUCountType>
                      <IsExpirationDatedProduct>false</IsExpirationDatedProduct>
                    </DescriptionData>
                    <ProductData>
                        <Home> 
                        <ProductType>
                            <BedAndBath>
                            <IdentityPackageType>traditional</IdentityPackageType>
                            </BedAndBath>
                            </ProductType>
                        <Parentage>child</Parentage>
                         <VariationData> 
                         <VariationTheme>Size-Color</VariationTheme>
                          <Size>S</Size>
                          <Color>blue</Color>
                          </VariationData> 
                          <Material>cotton</Material> 
                          <ThreadCount>10</ThreadCount> 
                        </Home>
                    </ProductData>
                    <IsHeatSensitive>false</IsHeatSensitive>
                  </Product>
                </Message>
              </AmazonEnvelope>';
```

Comment: This helped me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39107142/amazon-mws-product-feed-with-relationships